# Проверить лежат ли в массиве числа Фибоначчи

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет!
Имеется массив целых чисел, и мне нужно сделать проверку, соответствуют ли элементы массива числам Фибоначчи.
Если соответствуют я делаю Array.Reverse().
Как мне сделать такую проверку?

Comment: а как бы ты делал такую проверку вручную, без c#?

Comment: Даже не знаю, просто очень много вариантов того что может прийти вместо фибоначи.

Comment: и что с того? Что от этого вообще зависит? Ровным счетом ничего.

Comment: Глядя на число вы сможете сказать это число Фибоначчи или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static bool FibonacciEquals(int[] row)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Length - 2; i++)
        if (row[i] + row[i + 1] != row[i + 2])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Такой метод работает, даже если ряд начинается не с `0, 1`. Но главное, чтобы числа были именно по порядку и без случайных чисел между нужными. То есть, просто ряд фибоначчи.

Comment: Например массив `[10, 20, 30]` - это числа Фибоначчи? Или [-3, -5, -8]?

Comment: Любые массивы длины один и два будут признаны фибоначчиевыми. :(

Comment: @Stanislav VolodarskiyНу с первым соглашусь, а со вторым на вики сказано что Фибоначчи может быть и [отрицательным](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Числа_Фибоначчи)

Comment: Ряд для отрицательных индексов: f(1)=1, f(0)=0, f(-1)=1, f(-2)=-1, f(-3)=2, f(-4)=-3, f(-5)=5, f(-6)=-8, f(-7)=13, .... Среди этих чисел нет числа -5.

Answer (score 0):

`MakeFibs` строит множество всех чисел Фибоначчи, который помещаются в `int`.  `AreAllFibs` проверяет все числа массива на принадлежность множеству чисел Фибоначчи:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

HashSet<int> MakeFibs() {
    HashSet<int> fibs = new HashSet<int>();
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    fibs.Add(a);
    fibs.Add(b);
    // a + b <= Int32.MaxValue
    while (a <= Int32.MaxValue - b) {
        (a, b) = (b, a + b);
        fibs.Add(b);
    }
    return fibs;
}
HashSet<int> fibs = MakeFibs();

bool AreAllFibs(int[] numbers) {
    foreach (int n in numbers) {
        if (!fibs.Contains(n)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

Console.WriteLine(AreAllFibs(new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 1836311903}));
Console.WriteLine(AreAllFibs(new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 33, 1836311903}));
```

> ```
> $ csc -nologo fibs.cs && mono fibs.exe
> True
> False
> ```